# Como inicializar essa função de PhotoImage do tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além de importar o tkinter, como eu chamo a função, por exemplo: _show(?, 'o título'), o que coloco na primeira variável que é de imagem? Mostre um exemplo qualquer se ela estiver no desktop.

Comment: Sempre dê preferência a compartilhar o código em vez de uma imagem, isso possibilita que outras pessoas possam usar seu código como base, facilita apontar correções e adaptações. Além disso, você conseguiria ser um pouco mais claro? Eu realmente não entendi o que você deseja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe `PhotoImage` do `tkinter` é usada para mostrar imagens em `Label`s, `Button`s, `Canvas` e `Text`.

O método `_show()` é um método interno do objeto `Image`; Não deve ser chamado diretamente. Uma dica para isso é que ele começa com um `_`; é um método interno, um detalhe de implementação que é chamado pelo próprio PIL.

Se você está **criando** um método `_show`, está tentando modificar a forma como o PIL mostrará imagens, mas você não deve chamar esse método diretamente.

Pra terminar segue um exemplo de uso da classe `PhotoImage`, onde uma imagem é inserida dentro de uma área de texto `tkinter.Text`:

[image: resultado]

```
img = """
R0lGODlhIAAgAKIFAAAAAACt74xzUsbGxv/3AAAAAAAAAAAAACH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwHoAAAh+QQF
CgAHACwAAAAAIAAgAAADuBi63P4wyrmApbjam+nmkiCK0QdGwqCSj3k+asw2LhXfQrthtww4Ox4u9wp8
KKlVTnFy/VCjZUXjDEkZT6NJm11Ev1PmlssQ9ZRMcY2sSJ4HgqCTE3Sfl88a58vnG9VyfYJRf1xBAYOD
aYBjVyiLho0YeIySSItze5OQkVptmwoEoqIWox9xo6mqAqqmAKakca+tqay0paSztrS1vLgEp7O8oruq
v8AWssPErS6ry6PFuNPCxcO7CQAAIfkEBQYABwAsAQABABcAHQAAA4IYugwOLMr13ryhWiy1i0J4eZIw
DKNGKSc6VV3QRmRDAa7ibTe/qx7XbxgICXS7DIRXPP6QIKNT1YAoQq1BsrowZWtVq7e17UrPgjJ6/Wyu
pUo1J147YoZiDv46p8OKGASCBA6CGmmDiYqFD4ZpAIqRkIWJApGXkxoElpeLhoedBAkAADs=
"""
import tkinter as t

root = t.Tk()
img = t.PhotoImage(data=img)
text = t.Text(root)
text.insert(t.END, "Olá, aqui está a imagem:\n")
text.image_create(t.INSERT, image=img)
text.insert(t.END, "  Obrigado!")
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, pelo que eu entendi, você quer colocar uma imagem na sua interface, se for isso mesmo, esse é um código mínimo para você adicionar uma imagem na sua interface.

```
try:
   from tkinter import *
except:
   from Tkinter import *

tela = Tk()

imagem_blender = PhotoImage(file="low_poly.png")
foto = Label(tela, image=imagem_blender)
foto.grid(row=1,column=1)

tela.mainloop()
```

No caso, a imagem **low_poly.png"** está na mesma pasta que o script com esse código, ok?
[image: Script mostrando a foto na interface gráfica]